# Google Data Studio how to replace a string character by position?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

I am new into Google Data Studio and I am trying to cleanse some Google Analytic data.

For example I have a filed called page which shows the page name. For some pages I have  duplicates e.g: contact/product/car and contact/product/car/ (ending in this case with /)

I want to create a field that always replace  the last charterer of the page name if it ends with  '/' with a space

I have tried this function:  REPLACE(ENDS_WITH(Page,"/"), '/','')

But is not working instead giving me true or false.

Someone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use regular expression for doing this job:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Page,"/$","")
```